# I could not click licence agreement 'Accept' button in Hololens 2 Emulator

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I just launched the emulator App by double clicking it. It loaded (loading time is 10 to 15 min) with an audio to accept Microsoft licence agreement and login with current Microsoft id. It shows the licence agreement window as shown in below image:

[Hololens Emulator Licence Agreement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OceMm.png)

I could not click the Accept button. So I could not proceed further. I used alt+mouse drag to bring the hand, but either the hand does not appear or sometimes even if it appears and moves, no raycast to point on the button. I tried toggling the Use mouse, use keyboard for simulation check boxes.

Emulator version: 10.0.20346.1002

My device sepc:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz,
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable),
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Windows Spec:

Edition Windows 10 Enterprise,
Version 21H1,
OS build    19043.1023,
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0

Windows SDK version - 10.0.20348.1

GPU: Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070,
DirectX version: 12,
Driver model: WDDM 2.7

Comment: It is a Pressable button, you can interact it with the Collidable fingertip. So, please switch your hand gesture to “Point” first, and then move back and forth to imitate Tap behavior. Please let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you @Hernando-MSFT. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hernando - MSFT for helping me. The Accept button in the Licence agreemnet window can be clicked by moving back and forth the hand using W,A,S,D keys.

Previously i thought that i should click using a raycast pointer. It would be nice if i can click using raycast because the current approach is very difficult for any new users.

Additionally, sometimes mouse and keyboard inputs doesn't worked for me. This is because the 'Use Mouse' and 'Use Keyboard' check-boxes under the Simulation Panel is disabled. We have to ensure they are enabled for using mouse and keyboard for simulation inputs.